# Hypothesis-test; test about equal sample means

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I'm asked to formulate and do a test of the hypothesis that the sample mean (average grade) of math students and economic students are equal. Data below:

[image: Data]

I'm not sure how to "attack" this problem. I already did a exercise where I was asked to test the hypothesis that the variance of male and female math students were the same.

But now, when the math-students are devided in two "subgroups"; male-students and female-students/, and the economic-students consists of only one subgroup (both males and females), I'm not sure how to begin.

Can I somehow add the two sample means and use this "pooled" sample mean as a representative sample mean for math students and then just do a regular t-test, or how should I move forward? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Suppose $n = n_x + n_y$ is the number of economics students, $n_x$ being the number of male math students, $n_y$ being the number of math economics students.

Then the aggregate sample mean is$$\begin{align}\bar{X} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{110}x_i+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{38}y_i}{n} &= \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{110}x_i}{n}+\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{38}y_i}{n} \\&= \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{110}x_i}{n_x}\left(\dfrac{n_x}{n}\right) + \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{38}y_i}{n_y}\left(\dfrac{n_y}{n}\right) \\&= \bar{X}_x\left(\dfrac{n_x}{n}\right)+\bar{X}_y\left(\dfrac{n_y}{n}\right)\text{.}\end{align}$$
The aggregate sample variance $S^2$ is
$$\begin{align}S^2 &= \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{110}\left(x_i - \bar{X}\right)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{38}\left(y_i - \bar{Y}\right)}{n-1} \\&= \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{110}\left(x_i - \bar{X}_x\right)}{n-1} + \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{38}\left(y_i - \bar{X}_y\right)}{n-1} \\
&= \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{110}\left(x_i - \bar{X}_x\right)}{n_x-1}\left(\dfrac{n_x - 1}{n-1}\right) + \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{38}\left(y_i - \bar{X}_y\right)}{n-1}\left(\dfrac{n_y - 1}{n-1}\right) \\
&= S_x^2\left(\dfrac{n_x - 1}{n-1}\right) + S_y^2\left(\dfrac{n_y - 1}{n-1}\right)\text{.}\end{align}$$

Comment: So it's okay to "pool" the sample means and variances like that? I couldn't find any theorem for this, but I was thinking that you could add them in the way you proposed because E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y) .
Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Kristian This is very much related to the concept of double expectation, which states $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]]$. Suppose $X$ is the grade of an economics student, and $Y$ is an indicator random variable given by $$Y = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if male} \\
0, & \text{if female.}\end{cases}$$
Then $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y = 1]\Pr\left(Y = 1\right) + \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y = 0]\Pr\left(Y = 0\right)$. Oftentimes, this is referred to as a "weighted average."

Comment: Cool! One last question - you wrote $S^2$. You meant $S$ (the weighted sample standarddeviation), right?? Because otherwise, the weighted sample variance for the math students would be $S^2=4,93$ and for the economics student it would be $S^2=(3,58^2)=12,8164$

Comment: @Kristian Actually, I should have $S_x^2$ and $S_y^2$. Edited.